# Cant access image data in cakephp 2.0 through custom form

Tags: html, cakephp-2.0

I have created one function to add users. The parameters are username,email,password and profile image.

```
<form name="User" method="post" action="http://192.168.1.100/filmtastic/api/users/adduser" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr><td><label>username:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>password:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>email:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Image:</label></td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Now in my `UserController` i have:

```
public function api_adduser() {

$this->layout = false;
$this->request->data['User']= $this->request->data;
if($this->request->data['User'] != array()) {
    pr($this->request->data); die();
    }
 }
```

here i debug the data which is passed by that HTML form and optput is like

```
Array
(
    [username] => jack roy
    [password] => jack
    [email] => jack@yahoo.com
    [submit] => Submit
    [User] => Array
        (
            [username] => jack roy
            [password] => jack
            [email] => jack@yahoo.com
            [submit] => Submit
        )

)
```

The problem is that it will not show me the image array. can you tell me how i will get that image array which suppose to look like

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => 06_01_2009_0692878001231258160_nanzig.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php368F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 81167
        )

)
```

Comment: can you show the html of the form?

Comment: Please stop editing this question. I'll do it for you

Comment: @mehul, see my answer. It's more comfortable to create form input elements via the [`FormHelper`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply forgot to set the form mime type to `multipart/form-data`. Here is my demo view, called `add.ctp`

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));

echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->password('password');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->file('image');
echo $this->Form->submit();

echo $this->Form->end();
```

Here is the `UserController`

```
class UserController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function add() {
        pr($this->request->data);
    }

}
```

And here is how the result looks like when you submit the form

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [name] => admin
            [password] => admin
            [email] => asdf@qwerty.com
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cakephp-book.odt
                    [type] => application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpKniokr
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 170247
                )

        )

)
```

Here is a dump of the generated HTML which you may want to use on your *external* page (may I ask **why???**). Note how many things the `FormHelper` adds... I wonder why you build an external view if your application is still accessing your server directly...

```
  <form action="/test/cakedemo/user/add" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UserAddForm"
  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
    </div>

    <div class="input text">
      <label for="UserName">Name</label><input name="data[User][name]" 
        id="UserName" />
    </div><input name="data[User][password]" type="password" id="UserPassword" />

    <div class="input text">
      <label for="UserEmail">Email</label><input name="data[User][email]" type="text"
      id="UserEmail" />
    </div><input type="file" name="data[User][image]" id="UserImage" />

    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: to call this function i am not using the cakephp add file like .ctp extension. i have created one HTML form which is not in my "wamp/www", means its on another drive. and from that form i want to submit data: the form syntax is             <form name="User" method="post" action="http://192.168.1.100/project/api/users/adduser" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @mehul so you'd better follow Cake's naming conventions for form fields, ie something like `<input name="data[User][image]" />`

Comment: its iphone application backend and data is posting from iphone so may be its create problem at that time

Comment: @mehul I dumped the HTML generated for the form. iPhone posting doesn't mean anything, the iPhone is certainly able to display a webpage, so what you are trying to do is pointless. Unless you build a native HTTP client - IMHO a waste of resources. However if you manually build the `POST` request, you need to use *prefixed names* for input pieces like `data[User][image]` instead of the simple `image`